# How to make nesting set in swift?

Tags: swift

below three set how to make one set? . i mean one nested set

```
var nameSets : Set<String> = ["Nazmul","Hasan","Prince"]
var countrySets : Set<String> = ["UK","London","Bangladesh"]
var securitys : Set<Int> = [2904,99895,8944]

//work
var addresSets : Set = [nameSet,countrySet] 
//cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type 'Set'
 var addresSets : Set = [nameSet,countrySet,security]
// type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
var addresSets : Set<Any> = [nameSet,countrySet,security]
```

Comment: A set of sets sounds really odd. Does it need to be set of sets, as opposed to, say, an array of sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve here, however first of all let's clean up your code

```
let names: Set = ["Nazrul", "Hasan", "Prince"]
let countries: Set = ["UK", "London", "Bangladesh"]
let securities: Set = [2904, 99895, 8944]
```

We have 2 `Set(s)` of `String` and 1 `Set` of `Int`.

### names and countries

Now let's create a new set which will contain `names` and `countries`.

```
let all: Set = [names, countries]
```

The inferred type of `all` is `Set<Set<String>>`.

### names, countries and securities

Let's change how `all` is populated now

```
let all: Set = [names, countries, securities]
error: argument type 'Set<_>' does not conform to expected type 'Any'
```

Now the compiler needs a little help to figure out how `all` should be defined. The right definition is `Set<Set<AnyHashable>>` so

```
let all: Set<Set<AnyHashable>> = [names, countries, securities]
```

### Result

Now `all` contains the 3 original `Set(s)`.

```
[
    Set([AnyHashable(99895), AnyHashable(8944), AnyHashable(2904)]),
    Set([AnyHashable("Nazmul"), AnyHashable("Prince"), AnyHashable("Hasan")]),
    Set([AnyHashable("London"), AnyHashable("Bangladesh"), AnyHashable("UK")])
]
```

Comment: I would understand that a set called `union` would be the result of an union operation of two sets.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: You are right, I used the wrong name. Let me update my code.

Comment: we code 10% of our time and think about proper naming the remaining 90%.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Again I agree with you :D Just updated my answer!